# C++ container for storing sorted unique values with different predicates for sorting and uniqueness

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, stl, stdset

I have a record with 2 fields (say, A and B). 2 instances of the record should be considered equal, if their As are equal. On the other hand, a collection of the record instances should be sorted by the B field.

Is there a container like std::set, which can be defined with two different predicates, one for sorting and one for uniqueness, so I could avoid explicit sorting and just append elements? If no, how can it be workarounded?

Regards,

Comment: Why not use an `std::set` and implement `operator<` in terms of `record::B` and `operator==` in terms of `record::A`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Because `std::set` doesn't use `==` at all? This means it would allow duplicate elements by the OP's semantics.

Comment: @Angew [cppreference tells me](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp): "`Key` must meet the requirements of `EqualityComparable`", is that wrong then?

Comment: It is not at-first apparent the required ordering for a `std::set` can be met with the conditions you've imposed. It requires a [*strict weak ordering*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which, among other things, mandates that `if !((a<b) || (b<a)) then a == b`. Element identity in a `std::set` is defined as such. If you can manage to shoehorn your constrictions into that mandate, great, but it doesn't immediately seem you can.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant ... and get escorted out of the campus by the code sanity police? BTW std::set doesn't use == for uniqueness.

Comment: @n.m. excuse me, but this inconsistency is not my fault. OP asked how to implement something that compares less-than and greater-than based on member B and compares equal or unequal based on member A. Yeah, that's pretty bad design. I didn't suggest that he should do this. I only proposed a possible implementation of the bad design he wants to realize. As to `operator==`: does this mean that the reference page I linked to is incorrect?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Yes, it seems incorrect (at least in C++11). 23.2.4/3 specifically calls out a distinction between "key equivalence" and `==`. The latter is not used anywhere in the definition of `AssociativeContainer` requirements or `std::set`. It seems the same in C++03 as well.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I don't think the page is incorrect. The link you provided makes specific mention that to use the `operator ==` and `operator !=` *of two `std::set` objects* the `Key` must be EqualityComparable. that does not mean it is an intrinsic requirement of `std::set` by itself.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant In reference to WhozCraig's comment, the page you've linked even says "`Key` must meet the requirements of `EqualityComparable` **in order to use overloads (1-2).**" So it's *not* a general requirement of `std::set`.

Comment: @WhozCraig The C++ standard does not require `operator<` and `operator==` to be consistent in this sense. Rather, it simply defines key equivalence as `!((k1 < k2) || (k2 < k1))`.

Comment: @n.m. If my notation for *equivalence* was perceived as `operator ==`, I apologize. I would have thought what I wrote was clear, but apparently not.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in the standard library which would support your use case directly. You could use [Boost.MultiIndexContainer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) for this purpose, though. Something like this:

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  Record,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<member<Record, decltype(Record::B), &Record::B>>,
    hashed_unique<member<Record, decltype(Record::A), &Record::A>>
  >
> RecordContainer;
```

(Code assuming correct headers and `using namespace` directives for brevity).

The idea is to create a container with two indices, one which will guarantee the ordering based on `B` and the other which will guarantee uniqueness based on `A`. `decltype()` in the code can of course be replaced by the actual types of `A` and `B` which you know, but I don't.

The order of the indices matters slightly, since for convenience, the container itself offers the same interface as its first index. You can always access any index by using `container.get()`, though.

The code is not intended as a copy&paste solution, but as a starting point. You can add customisations, index tags etc. Refer to Boost documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a container like std::set, which can be defined with two different predicates, one for sorting and one for uniqueness*

std::set defines whether particular element is unique OR not in terms of the sorting criteria you provide to it( by default it uses less<>) . There's no need to explicitly pass another criteria for checking equality of elements.
With that said, however, you can use a predicate with algorithms to check for equality of elements of std::set.